# Detect when editing ends on one uitextfield but starts on another

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, detect

I just created two functions, `slideAuthViewUp` and `slideAuthViewDown` that are called when you enter the login or password `UITextfield`. It is useful in landscape mode to see the whole authentication form.

These are called like below:

```
[passwordTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(slideAuthFormUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
[passwordTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(slideAuthFormDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];

[loginTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(slideAuthFormUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
[loginTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(slideAuthFormDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

Now, the problem is when I click on the password textfield the slideAuthFromDown is called by the login textfield and then the slideAuthFormUp is called by the password textfield. So the authentication form goes down and up in a really short time which is not what I want. I would like this form to stay up during this short time.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform the slide down after a short delay, and if a slide up happens within that time, cancel the scheduled selector. So...have an intermediary method...

```
- (void)delayedSlideDown {
  [self performSelector:@selector(slideAuthFormDown) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
}
```

Then use...

```
[passwordTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(delayedSlideDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

And finally add the following line to slideAuthFormUp....

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

You may need to play with the 0.2 delay...

Comment: Very clear. Thank you, It's working great. I just have a little problem when I come back on the login textfield but I'll figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Great, thanks! Even a delay of **0.0** (!) is working for me, and I used `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(...) object:...` to avoid clobbering any other selector performing.

Answer (score 0):

hmm... have a look at [this example](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/c8c8d822-7102-4b25-83f2-c5cf1a2f2d9b/5687b0d9332d8d1f232d988e84d50467)  given in the website [here](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/02/27/keyboard-tutorial-part-3-add-a-toolbar-to-the-keyboard/) the Appcodeblog. The code is from there.. I hold no responsibility for the code i am just referencing my evernote clip from that website. which has everything at one place. ... starting from tutorial 1 to 3.